# JS: Print main diagonal of array using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, cycle

How to print the main diagonale of array without using cycle for(...) but using array methods instead?

---

```
 const arr = [
 [1,6,8,-1],
 [0,2,-6,5],
 [0,-5,3,6],
 [9,-1,1,0] ];
```

---

Here elements arr[0][0] = 1, arr[1][1]=2, arr[2][2]=3, arr[3][3]=0 are elements of the main diagonale. We can print them using cycle for:

---

```
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    console.log(arr[i][i]);
}
```

---

But is there a possibility to print them using methods .forEach .map or another one?

Comment: What's a main diagonale?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Danmoreng array[i][j], index i = index j

Comment: Can you add an example ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but essentially they use the loops inside:

```js
var a = [
 [1,6,8,-1],
 [0,2,-6,5],
 [0,-5,3,6],
 [9,-1,1,0] ];

var r = a.map((v, i) => v[i]);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array methods to get the same result, but they use for-loops inside anyways and in this case a single for-loop looks more readable to me.

However, if you really wanted to, you could do it like so:

```js
const arr = [
 [1,6,8,-1],
 [0,2,-6,5],
 [0,-5,3,6],
 [9,-1,1,0] ];
 
const result = arr.map((sub_array, index) => sub_array.filter((number, index2) => index === index2));
console.log(result);
```